# Continuos update of sprites in andEngine

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

How can a sprite(say track) be continuosly looking/pointing at another sprite(say boxy) ... the thing i have tried is here(in onPopulate Scene) but it doesnt work :( .

### Track(currently/Default pointing up)

[image: Tracky]

```
track.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void reset() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

                float centre_tracky_width = track.getWidth() / 2;
                float centre_tracky_height = track.getHeight() / 2;
                float centre_boxy_width = boxy.getWidth() / 2;
                float centre_boxy_height = boxy.getHeight() / 2;
                float x_d = (centre_tracky_width - centre_boxy_width);
                float y_d = (centre_tracky_height - centre_boxy_height);
                float dtoboxy = (float) Math.pow(
                        (float) (Math.pow(y_d, 2) + Math.pow(x_d, 2)), 0.5);
                track.setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees((float) Math
                        .acos(y_d / dtoboxy)));


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,

```
track.setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees((float) Math
                    .acos(y_d / dtoboxy)));
```

should be :

```
track.setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees((float) Math
                    .atan2(y_d / dtoboxy)));
```